# Using Generics to combine 2 separate almost identical functions

Tags: swift, generics

I have 2 functions I use to provide a layer over some networking code.

Historically there was only 1 function, but I have just sat down to expand this and realised they are identical apart from some types.

Is it possible to combine these using generics?

Or is that over kill?

I have been reading a little and am struggling to understand how generics could be implemented here

```
func profile(with endpoint: ProfilesEndpoint, method: HTTPMethod, body: String?, headers: [String: String]?, completion: @escaping (Either<ProfileResponse>) -> Void) {
    var request = endpoint.request
    request.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    if let body = body {
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
    }

    if let headers = headers {
        for (key, value) in headers {
            request.addValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }
    }

    execute(with: request, completion: completion)
}

func identity(with endpoint: IdentityEndpoint, method: HTTPMethod, body: String?, headers: [String: String]?, completion: @escaping (Either<OAuthTokenResponse>) -> Void) {
    var request = endpoint.request
    request.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    if let body = body {
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
    }

    if let headers = headers {
        for (key, value) in headers {
            request.addValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }
    }

    execute(with: request, completion: completion)
}
```

I have tried but get an error that `Value of type 'T' has no member 'request'`

```
func request<T: Comparable, X: Comparable>(with endpoint: T, method: HTTPMethod, body: String?, headers: [String: String]?, completion: @escaping (Either<X>) -> Void) {
    var request = endpoint.request
    request.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    if let body = body {
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
    }

    if let headers = headers {
        for (key, value) in headers {
            request.addValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }
    }

    execute(with: request, completion: completion)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got that error because not all types have this variable named `request`. Generics doesn't suit this question because you are referring to a specific class (it's not general).

Here's two ideas that will solve your problem:

## Method 1-

#### I think it's the best option as it's intuitive- each function has it's own purpose and description, while code recycles and remains simple

change

`func request<T: Comparable, X: Comparable>(with endpoint: T, method: HTTPMethod, body: String?, headers: [String: String]?, completion: @escaping (Either<X>) -> Void)`

to

`private func request(urlRequest: URLRequest, method: HTTPMethod, body: String? , headers: [String: String]?, completion: @escaping (response: HttpResponse) -> Void)`

Then from `profile(...)` and `identity(...)` you can call your request function-

```
func profile(with endpoint: ProfilesEndpoint, method: HTTPMethod, body: String?, headers: [String: String]?, completion: @escaping (Either<ProfileResponse>) -> Void) {
    var urlRequest = endpoint.request
    // call request(urlRequest: urlRequest, ...) and handle completion
}

func identity(with endpoint: IdentityEndpoint, method: HTTPMethod, body: String?, headers: [String: String]?, completion: @escaping (Either< OAuthTokenResponse>) -> Void) {
    var urlRequest = endpoint.request
    // call request(urlRequest: urlRequest, ...) and handle completion 
}

private func request(urlRequest: URLRequest, method: HTTPMethod, body: String? , headers: [String: String]?, completion: @escaping (response: HttpResponse) -> Void){ 

    var request = urlRequest
    .
    .
    .
 }
```

## Method 2-

Create a protocol named `Endpoint`, and implement it on ProfileEndpoint and IdentityEndpoint.

```
protocol Endpoint{
    var request: URLRequest { get }
}

class ProfilesEndpoint: Endpoint {
    // this class must contain variable request because it implements Endpoint protocol
    var request: URLRequest{
        .
        .
        return ...
    }
}
class IdentityEndpoint: Endpoint {
    // this class must contain variable request because it implements Endpoint protocol
    var request: URLRequest{
        .
        .
        return ...
    }
}
```

Then you can change your request function to-

(I'm really not familiar with `Either<>` so I'm not sure about your completion)

```
func request(with endpoint: Endpoint, method: HTTPMethod, body: String?, headers: [String: String]?, completion: @escaping (Either<X>) -> Void) {

    var request = endpoint.request
    request.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    if let body = body {
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
    }

    if let headers = headers {
        for (key, value) in headers {
            request.addValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }
    }

    execute(with: request, completion: completion)
}
```

You can call this function with either `IdentityEndpoint` or `ProfilesEndpoint` because they both conform to `protocol Endpoint`- who declared variable `request`, so for sure both classes will have this variable too.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't easy to find a proper solution since it isn't something I can directly copy paste into the playground and play with it. Anyway, I hope this will work:

```
protocol Endpoint {
    var request: URLRequest { get } 
}

extension IdentityEndpoint: Endpoint {}
extension ProfilesEndpoint: Endpoint {}

func genericFunc<T>(with endpoint: Endpoint, method: HTTPMethod, body: String?: headers: [String: String]?, completion: @escaping (Either<T>) -> Void) {
    // You can repeat the same stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and a good idea to replace both your functions with a single one using generics. To do this you first need to define a protocol with the common functionality of your endpoints. If I see this correctly it should look something like this:

```
protocol Endpoint {
    associatedtype Response

    var request: URLRequest { get }
}
```

Maybe you need to add some constraints to the `Response` associated type. This depends on your `execute` function.

With this you then can define your generic `request` function like this:

```
func request<E: Endpoint>(with endpoint: E, method: HTTPMethod, body: String?, headers: [String: String]?, completion: @escaping (Either<E.Response>) -> Void) { ... }
```